# CSS center vertically Div into a Div

Tags: html, css, center, vertical-alignment

I have a problem, I need to center vertically the div containing "THREE:" respect to the div containig the image, how can I do this?

Here is my markup:

```
<div class="content">
   <div class="tablediv"></div>
      <div class="onecolumn center"><h3>TITLE</h3></div>
   </div>
   <div class="tablediv">
      <div class="threecolumns left">ONE:</div>
      <div class="threecolumns center">&nbsp;</div>
      <div class="threecolumns center">- - -</div>
   </div>
   <div class="tablediv">
      <div class="threecolumns left">TWO:</div>
      <div class="threecolumns center">&nbsp;</div>
      <div class="threecolumns center">- - -</div>
   </div>
   <div class="tablediv">
      <div class="threecolumns left">THREE:</div>
      <div class="threecolumns center">&nbsp;</div>
      <div class="threecolumns center"><img class="imageseason" src="http://www.videcom.com/Portals/0/linux_u2.png"></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Using the following stylesheet:

```
.center {
    text-align: center;
}

.left {
    text-align: left;
}

.right {
    text-align: right;
}

.imageseason {
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
}

.divtable {
    position: relative;
    clear: left; 
    width: 90%;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
}

.onecolumn {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    padding-top: 10px;
}

.twocolumns {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    padding-top: 10px;
}

.threecolumns {
    float: left;
    width: 33.333333333%;
    padding-top: 10px;
}

.fourcolumns {
    float: left;
    width: 25%;
    padding-top: 10px;
}

.fivecolumns {
    float: left;
    width: 20%;
    padding-top: 10px;
}
```

This is the fiddle: [JSFiddle Snippet](http://jsfiddle.net/massimilianos/5en7zhka/34/)

Comment: Why don't you use `display:table/table-row/table-cell` for this layout, instead of floating elements? And then you will be able to use `vertical-align` property.

Comment: in your post some basic code should be also provided, not just a div to circumvent the SO check

Comment: Please do not use a filler code element just to bypass the code requirement — it is there for a reason, to encourage you to understand your code instead of pasting it in a fiddle and asking us to troubleshoot it for you, and also to help you with formulating a specific problem statement. I have inserted the code from your fiddle into your question—don't do this again next time.

Comment: @Vucko how can I do this? Thank you!

Comment: @Terry you raised me some reputation point for this reason? Thank you so much! You are very very good!

Comment: @Fabrizio Calderan you raised me some reputation point for this reason? Thank you so much! You are very very good!

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you need ??? ... two things to note about it:
1) Always use position and display attributes
2) Spaces (or break lines) also count as child elements, that is why using 33.33% three times does not work when there are spaces between divs

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
<style>

div.tablediv {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
}

.center {
    text-align: center;
}

.left {
    text-align: left;
}

.right {
    text-align: right;
}

.imageseason {
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
}

.threecolumns {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 33.33%;
    padding-top: 10px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="content">
   <div class="tablediv">
      <div class="onecolumn center"><h3>TITLE</h3></div>
   </div>
   <div class="tablediv"><div class="threecolumns left">ONE:</div><div class="threecolumns center">&nbsp;</div><div class="threecolumns center">- - -</div></div>
   <div class="tablediv"><div class="threecolumns left">TWO:</div><div class="threecolumns center">&nbsp;</div><div class="threecolumns center">- - -</div></div>
   <div class="tablediv"><div class="threecolumns left">THREE:</div><div class="threecolumns center">&nbsp;</div><div class="threecolumns center"><img class="imageseason" src="http://www.videcom.com/Portals/0/linux_u2.png"></div></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try using a table instead

```
<table class="some_table">
    <tr>
        <td>ONE:</td>
        <td>---</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>TWO:</td>
        <td>---</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>THREE:</td>
        <td><img class="imageseason" src="http://www.videcom.com/Portals/0/linux_u2.png"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I don't want to use a table, any ideas?